# Print json string in one line using circe in scala

Tags: scala, circe

I want to print json to string in one line.

```
    case class Data(e: Option[String])

    object Data {
      implicit val dEncoder = deriveDecoder[Data]
      implicit val dDecoder = deriveEncoder[Data]
    }

    case class Random(a: String,b: String, c: Int,d: Data)

    object Random {
      implicit val rEncoder = deriveDecoder[Random]
      implicit val rDecoder = deriveEncoder[Random]
    }
```

`val res = Random("a","b", 1, Data("e"))`

when i do **res.asJson.toString**, i get:
    
    `{
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b",
    "c":1,
    "d":
    {
      "e": "e" 
    }
    }`

but i want it to be printed in one line without \n as using circe.

`**{"a": "a","b": "b", "c": 1,d:{"e": "e"}}**`

Answer (score 14):

If you don't mind stripping other unnecessary whitespace characters:

```
@ res.asJson.noSpaces
res9: String = "{\"a\":\"a\",\"b\":\"b\",\"c\":1,\"d\":{\"e\":\"e\"}}"

@ println(res.asJson.noSpaces)
{"a":"a","b":"b","c":1,"d":{"e":"e"}}
```